# How can I set a time interval based on current date/time using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, datetime, vue.js, vuetify.js, bootstrap-vue

Lets assume that current date/time is 03/29/2020 02:10 PM. Then i want to display 7 sets of time with fifteen minutes interval that will be 01:30 PM , 01:45 PM , 02:00 PM , 02:15 PM, 02:30 PM , 02:45 PM and 03:00 PM.

```
Current Date/Time =  03/29/2020 02:10 PM

<div :key="timeList">
      <button>{{timeList}}</button>
</div>
```

How can i display seven sets of time in timeList as 15 minutes interval for currentTime as

- 01:30 PM
- 01:45 PM
- 02:00 PM
- 02:15 PM
- 02:30 PM
- 02:45 PM
- 03:00 PM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you use `moment` for this. Even though this can be done by adding little more lines using without `moment`, but adding `moment` to your project will save time and energy.

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in timeList" :key="timeList">
      <button>{{item}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  ...
  ...
  data: {
     timeList: [
     ],
  },
 mounted: function(){
   const current = new moment();
   for(let i=0;i<5;i++){
      this.timeList.push(current.format("HH:mm"));
      current.add(15, "minutes");
   }

 }
})
</script>
```

Check moment here https://momentjs.com/docs/

Answer (score 2):

If the current time is 02:10, then the next 15 minute block starts at 02:15.

Anyway, you can use built–in formatting functions to get the appropriate format, e.g.

```js
/* 
** @param {Date} date: date to use for time blocks
** @param {number} mins: length of time block in minutes
**        should be an even divisor of 60, e.g. 5, 10, 12, 15
** @param {number} num: number of values to return
** @returns {Array} array of strings formatted as hh:mm ap
*/
function getTimes(date, mins, num) {
  // Copy date so don't affect original
  let d = new Date(date);
  // Get start of next block
  let dMins = d.getMinutes();
  let nextMin = Math.ceil(dMins/mins) * mins; 
  // If in first minute of first block, add 1
  if (!(dMins%mins)) nextMin += mins;
    
  d.setMinutes(nextMin, 0, 0);
  let result = [];
  let opts = {hour:'2-digit', minute:'2-digit', hour12:true};
  
  while (num--) {
    result.push(d.toLocaleString('en', opts));
    d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + mins);
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log(getTimes(new Date(), 15, 7));
```

Comment: This is my first project on Vue JS so just wanted to be clear is that function suppose to be inside monuted or method ?